# MassTransit - Configuration exception when adding consumers dynamically

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit

I am using MassTransit 8.0.5 with RabbitMQ for service bus implementation in my .NET 6 microservices. I published a message from Service-A and I can see the exchange created by namespace without any queue. The problem is happening when I start my consumer Service-B. It throws the following configuration exception.

[image]

Here is my configuration:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
    {
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        services.AddMassTransit(configure =>
        {
            configure.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
            configure.AddConsumers(assembly);

            configure.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
            {
                var rabbitSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<RabbitSettings>>().Value;
                var host = new Uri("rabbitmq://" + rabbitSettings.EventBusConnection);

                configurator.Host(host, h =>
                {
                    h.Username(rabbitSettings.EventBusUserName);
                    h.Password(rabbitSettings.EventBusPassword);
                });

                var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                    .Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(IntegrationEvent));

                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    var consumers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                        .Where(x => x.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IConsumer<>).MakeGenericType(type))).ToList();

                    if (consumers.Any())
                    {
                        // rabbitSettings.QueueName => service-b
                        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitSettings.QueueName, e =>
                            {
                                e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(InboxFilter<>), context);
                                foreach (var consumer in consumers)
                                {
                                    configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context, x => x.Exclude(consumer));

                                    var methodInfo = typeof(DependencyInjectionReceiveEndpointExtensions)
                                        .GetMethods()
                                        .Where(x => x.GetParameters()
                                            .Any(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(IServiceProvider)))
                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Consumer" && x.IsGenericMethod);

                                    var generic = methodInfo?.MakeGenericMethod(consumer);
                                    generic?.Invoke(e, new object[] { e, context, null });
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        return services;
    }
```

IntegrationEvent, which is excluded from topology, is my base type of all integration events. I am trying to add consumers dynamically, but could not figure out what's wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Working solution

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        services.AddMassTransit(configure =>
        {
            configure.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

            var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).ToArray();
            var eventTypes = allTypes.Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(IntegrationEvent)).ToArray();
            Type[] consumerTypes = allTypes.Where(x => eventTypes.Any(et => x.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IConsumer<>).MakeGenericType(et)))).ToArray();

            configure.AddConsumers(consumerTypes);

            configure.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
            {
                var rabbitSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<RabbitSettings>>().Value;
                var host = new Uri("rabbitmq://" + rabbitSettings.EventBusConnection);

                configurator.Host(host, h =>
                {
                    h.Username(rabbitSettings.EventBusUserName);
                    h.Password(rabbitSettings.EventBusPassword);
                });

                configurator.UseCircuitBreaker(cb =>
                {
                    cb.TrackingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    cb.TripThreshold = 15;
                    cb.ActiveThreshold = 10;
                    cb.ResetInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                });

                configurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
                {
                    r.Ignore(typeof(ArgumentException),
                             typeof(ArgumentNullException),
                             typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException),
                             typeof(IndexOutOfRangeException),
                             typeof(DivideByZeroException),
                             typeof(InvalidCastException));

                    r.Intervals(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 }.Select(t => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t)).ToArray());
                });

                if (consumerTypes.Length > 0)
                {
                    configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitSettings.QueueName, e =>
                    {
                        e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(InboxFilter<>), context);
                        e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        return services;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, you can't call `ReceiveEndpoint()` with the same queue name twice.

Better answer, your configuration is a mess, and all that reflection is unnecessary. I've simplified it for you.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(configure =>
    {
        configure.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

        var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).ToList();

        var eventTypes = allTypes.Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(IntegrationEvent)).ToList();

        var consumerTypes = allTypes.Where(x => eventTypes.Any(et => x.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IConsumer<>).MakeGenericType(et)))).ToList();

        configure.AddConsumers(consumerTypes);

        configure.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
        {
            var rabbitSettings = context.GetService<IOptions<RabbitSettings>>().Value;
            var host = new Uri("rabbitmq://" + rabbitSettings.EventBusConnection);

            configurator.Host(host, h =>
            {
                h.Username(rabbitSettings.EventBusUserName);
                h.Password(rabbitSettings.EventBusPassword);
            });

            if (consumerTypes.Any())
            {
                // rabbitSettings.QueueName => service-b
                configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitSettings.QueueName, e =>
                {
                    e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(InboxFilter<>), context);
                    e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    return services;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @chris-patterson. It worked.  One last question if you don't mind. I know order matters. Is there any specific order for circuit breaker and retry policy? I use CB first in my edited question. Is it a problem?

Comment: If you're doing that many retries with the circuit breaker, and it's still failing, you might set your threshold lower. I would use the kill switch instead though, since it actually stops the endpoint instead of filling up the error queue. However, I would have to say, probably a really bad idea to use it since you have so many different likely unrelated consumers on a single receive endpoint. I would never put multiple consumers on a single queue that way.

Comment: You mean that each message/event should have its own queue, right? I have a few microservices using event driven architecture and choreography. If we count the compensation methods, there are lots of integration events. That's why I thought it was a good idea to have a single queue for each microservice. By the way, it would be great if your next YT video was about best practices like this.

Answer (score 0):

A small fix to above answer, you don't need to build serviceProvider on line 3, since configure.UsingRabbitMq already provides serviceProvider as a first argument

```
configure.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
{
    var rabbitSettings = context.GetService<IOptions<RabbitSettings>>().Value;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, updated my answer to remove that extra service provider usage copied from the original question.